# Weak-linking vs "--as-needed"

Tags: gcc, linker, jack, weak-linking

I'm having trouble with using a library that contains weak-symbols and the `--as-needed` linker flag.

#### Example

(This uses the [Jack](http://jackaudio.org) library)

```
$ cat <<EOF >myjack.c
#include <jack/weakjack.h>
#include <jack/jack.h>
int main() {
  if (jack_client_opent)
     jack_client_open("foobar", JackNoStartServer, 0, 0);
  else return 1;
  return 0;
}
EOF

$ gcc -o myjack myjack.c  -Wl,--no-as-needed -ljack

$ ./myjack && echo "ok" || echo "K.O."
ok

$ ldd myjack | grep jack
    libjack.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0 (0x00007f16f615f000)

$ gcc -o myjack myjack.c  -Wl,--as-needed -ljack

$ ./myjack && echo "ok" || echo "K.O."
K.O.

$ ldd myjack | grep jack

$
```

(The example code was edited to not segfault any more, as the segfault is not my actually problem)

#### The problem

It seems that the problem is:

- Jack declares *all* symbols as *weak* (if I include `<jack/weakjack.h>`). this is fine with me; I do want my symbols to stay weak.
  esp. my program is weakly linking against jack on OSX (`-weak_framework Jackmp`), which requires to include `<jack/weakjack.h>`
- When linking with `--as-needed`, the linker excludes any library, that does not reference at least one non-weak symbol. from the manpage:

> --as-needed causes a DT_NEEDED tag to only be emitted for
>              a library that at that point in the link satisfies a non-weak
>              undefined symbol reference from a regular object file

- some OSs (e.g. Ubuntu-16.04LTS) have `--as-needed` enabled by default.

Now I think that `--as-needed` is a nice linker feature to get rid of many really unneeded runtime dependencies.

However, I fail to see why a *weak* dependency is considered as *no dependency at all*. For me, a *weak* dependency is to enable *optional* features. I do want these features to be enabled if possible, and the decision whether this is possible should be a *runtime* decision. With the current behavior, it becomes a compile-time decision. (If I wanted that, I would simply disable the relevant code via some preprocessor magic).

One solution is obviously to just add `--no-as-needed` to the linker flags.
I don't want this: I do want to get rid of overlinking, if my distribution (or whoever compiles my binary) thinks this is the thing to do.

So I *might* turn on `as-needed` after linking in my known-weak library:

```
  gcc -o myjack myjack.c  -Wl,--no-as-needed -ljack -Wl,--as-needed ...
```

but this feels wrong as well, as then all libraries after my forced-needed library are suddenly forced to `--as-needed` (which might *not* be what my distribution or whoever compiles my binary thinks that this is the thing to do). It also seems to be adding a lot of cruft to the build chain, just because some library happens to export weak symbols only. I do not want to manually track all libraries that do this.

I also could of course simply *not* include `<jack/weakjack.h>`. The reason why it is included is because the application also works on OSX, where I do want to *optionally depend* on the JACK framework (so I link with `-weak_framework Jackmp`), and keep my program runnable in th absence of that framework.

I really don't want to clutter my application code because of the subtle differences between linkers on various platforms. This is probably the main issue I'm having with all this: why should *I* add platform-specific code to my application to cater for different linker specifics - I'd probably be OK with adding feature-specific code, e.g. not including `weakjack.h` if the compiler has no equivalent for `-weak_library` or `-weak_framework`; but currently it seems that the closest I can get is something like `#ifdef __APPLE__` which makes me shudder in this context).

So I'd really love some option to force libraries that only have weak symbols to be dylinked nevertheless.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> I'm having trouble with using a library that contains weak-symbols and the --as-needed linker flag.

No, you're not.

Find out where your `libjack.so` is, e.g.

```
$ locate libjack
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so.0.1.0
...
```

Then use `nm` to examine the symbol types of the JACK API in `libjack.so`:

```
$ nm -C -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so | grep jack_
000000000000e7e0 T jack_acquire_real_time_scheduling
000000000000d530 T jack_activate
000000000002ccf0 T jack_client_close
000000000000e820 T jack_client_create_thread
....
....
000000000000f340 T jack_uuid_empty
000000000000f320 T jack_uuid_parse
000000000000f2e0 T jack_uuid_to_index
000000000000f330 T jack_uuid_unparse
```

You'll find they are all type `T` ( = ordinary global symbol in text section: [`man nm`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nm)). There *are*
a few weak symbols in the library:

```
$ nm -C -D /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjack.so | egrep ' (w|W) '
                 w __cxa_finalize
                 w __gmon_start__
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses
0000000000025410 W std::ctype<char>::do_widen(char) const
0000000000014c10 W void std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_M_emplace_back_aux<unsigned short const&>(unsigned short const&)
0000000000014b10 W std::pair<std::_Rb_tree_iterator<unsigned short>, bool> std::_Rb_tree<unsigned short, unsigned short, std::_Identity<unsigned short>, std::less<unsigned short>, std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_M_insert_unique<unsigned short>(unsigned short&&)
0000000000014ad0 W std::_Rb_tree<unsigned short, unsigned short, std::_Identity<unsigned short>, std::less<unsigned short>, std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_M_erase(std::_Rb_tree_node<unsigned short>*)
```

But none of them are in the JACK API. Nothing you can do short of rebuilding your `libjack.so` is going to change that.
The right way to characterise your problem is:

*I'm having trouble linking a library with the `--as-needed` linker flag to a program in which
I decided to weaken all my references to that library*

The defining symbol references of the JACK API in `libjack.so` are all strong. You have
written a program directing the compiler to emit, in *your* object code, symbols that are
weak undefined references to the JACK API, and you are finding that, with *as-needed* linkage,
these weak references fail to compel linkage of `libjack.so` to provide their missing definitions.

> it seems that the problem is:
>
> jack declares all symbols as weak (if I include ).
>
> when linking with --as-needed, the linker excludes any library, that does not reference at least one non-weak symbol.
>
> some OSs (e.g. Ubuntu-16.04LTS) have --as-needed enabled by default.

The last two points are correct. The schism between distros that link shared libraries
*as-needed* by default and distros that don't goes back to Debian Wheezy, 2013,
which [went over to *as-needed*](https://wiki.debian.org/ToolChain/DSOLinking).
Since then, the Debian-derived distro-clan has followed suit while the RedHat/Fedora
clan has stuck with the *status quo ante*.

The first point is confused. `libjack.so`, as we've noted, exports a strongly defined
JACK API that you cannot alter by writing and compiling new code. 
If you include `<jack/weakjack.h>` in one of your source files, then *you* are
declaring all JACK API symbols weak, in your code, and the compiler will
give you an object file that contains only weak references to the JACK API. `<jack/weakjack.h>`
just defines macros that have that effect.

It would be surprising if an old and major linux library like `libjack`
has botched its adaptation to the *as-needed* schism. I suspect you've overlooked [some of
the small print about `jack/weakjack.h`](http://jackaudio.org/api/group__WeakLinkage.html):

> Detailed Description
>
> One challenge faced by developers is that of taking advantage of new features 
>   introduced in new versions of [ JACK ] while still supporting older versions of
>   the system. Normally, if an application uses a new feature in a library/API, 
>   it is unable to run on earlier versions of the library/API that do not support 
>   that feature. Such applications would either fail to launch or crash when an 
>   attempt to use the feature was made. This problem cane be solved using 
>   weakly-linked symbols.
>
> ...
>
> A concrete example will help. Suppose that someone uses a version of a JACK 
>   client we'll call "Jill". Jill was linked against a version of JACK that contains
>   a newer part of the API (say, jack_set_latency_callback()) and would like to use
>   it if it is available.
>
> When Jill is run on a system that has a suitably "new" version of JACK, this 
>   function will be available entirely normally. But if Jill is run on a system 
>   with an old version of JACK, the function isn't available.
>
> With normal symbol linkage, this would create a startup error whenever someone
>   tries to run Jill with the "old" version of JACK. However, **functions added to 
>   JACK after version 0.116.2 are all declared to have "weak" linkage** which means 
>   that their abscence doesn't cause an error during program startup. Instead, Jill
>   can test whether or not the symbol jack_set_latency_callback is null or not. 
>   If its null, it means that the JACK installed on this machine is too old to 
>   support this function. If its not null, then Jill can use it just like any other
>   function in the API. For example:
>
> ```
> if (jack_set_latency_callback) {
>     jack_set_latency_callback (jill_client, jill_latency_callback, arg);
> }
> ```
>
> **However, there are clients that may want to use this approach to parts of the** 
>   **JACK API that predate 0.116.2. For example, they might want to see if even** 
>   **really old basic parts of the API like jack_client_open() exist at runtime.**
>
> **Such clients should include <jack/weakjack.h> before any other JACK header**. 
>   **This will make the entire JACK API be subject to weak linkage, so that any and** 
>   **all functions can be checked for existence at runtime. It is important to** 
>   **understand that very few clients need to do this - if you use this feature you** 
>   **should have a clear reason to do so.**

[emphasis added]

This makes clear that a program, like yours, that takes the exceptional step of of including `jack/weakjack.h` for the purpose of weakening its references to the entire JACK API can be expected to run successfully only if it tests the definedness of every JACK API symbol before referencing it and handles the case in which it is not defined. Your program does not conform. This one does:

**myjack1.c**

```
#include <jack/weakjack.h>
#include <jack/jack.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    if (jack_client_open) { 
        jack_client_open("foobar", JackNoStartServer, 0, 0);
    } else {
        puts("`jack_client_open` is not available");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and do does this one:

**myjack2.c**

```
#include <jack/weakjack.h>
#include <jack/jack.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    jack_client_t * (*jack_client_open_fp)
        (const char *, jack_options_t,jack_status_t *,...) = jack_client_open;

    if (!jack_client_open_fp) {
        void * dsoh = dlopen("libjack.so",RTLD_LAZY);
        if (!dsoh) {
            fputs("`libjack` is not available\n",stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        *(void**)(&jack_client_open_fp) = dlsym(dsoh,"jack_client_open");
        if (!jack_client_open_fp) {
            fputs("`jack_client_open` is not available\n",stderr);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    jack_client_open_fp("foobar", JackNoStartServer, 0, 0);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

which sketches the usual approach to a discoverable API - apt
for a program meant to install and run on a system that
might not provide `libjack` at all. So you'd build it without reference to `libjack`
like:

```
gcc -o myjack2 myjack2.c -ldl
```

and on Ubuntu 17.04 - which *does* provide `libjack` - it might run like:

```
$ ./myjack2 
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for 4294967295, skipping unlock
```

So the library's T&Cs are in good order with respect to *as-needed* linkage. That
seems to leave you in a position of being independently dissatisfied that *as-needed* linkage works
the way it does, rather than in a different way that would allow you to weaken
all your references to the  JACK API and still get `libjack` to be *needed* by your weak references to its
API symbols:-

> I fail to see why a weak dependency is considered as no dependency at all. For me, 
>   a weak dependency is to enable optional features. I do want these features to be
>   enabled if possible, and the decision whether this is possible should be a 
>   runtime decision. With the current behavior, it becomes a compile-time decision.

Your view that a weak symbol reference gives rise to a *weak* linkage dependency on a library
that defines the symbol does not have a footing for the GNU linker. A program
depends on a library if its linkage needs a symbol definition that the libary provides; otherwise
it doesn't depend on that libary: there aren't weak and strong degrees of dependency. (The Darwin Mach-O linker does support a cognate distinction)

There are *weak symbols*, as opposed to the default and usual kind,
which is *strong*. *{weak|strong} symbol* is shorthand for *{weakly|strongly} referenced
symbol*, since the same symbol may be referenced in multiple linker input files,
sometimes or always weakly and sometimes or always strongly.

A strong symbol must have exactly one defining reference in the linkage.

A weak symbol is such that:

- The linker is not obliged to find a definition for it: it may remain undefined in the output file
- The linker is not obliged to fault multiple weak definitions of the same symbol
  in different input files. If exactly one defining reference within the linkage is
  strong, then that strong definition is picked and all weak ones ignored. If all 
  defining references in the linkage are weak then the linker will pick one at random.

From the first part of that it follows that an undefined weak reference to
a symbol does not give rise to a linkage dependency *at all*. A definition is
*not needed* and the fact that a definition is not needed is the result of a
decision by the programmer (e.g. `#include <jack/weak_jack.h>`) or perhaps by the
compiler. It is not reasonable to expect that the linker, if directed to link
only shared libraries that are *needed*, should then link libraries to furnish definitions
of symbols for which you or the compiler have told it that definitions are not needed.

If the linker *were* to behave like that in your case, *that* would constitute
a linktime decision to freeze and enable an API which, by including `jack/weak_jack.h`,
you have indicated you wish to reserve entirely for runtime discovery.

Linking your problem program with `-no-as-needed` is successful as a way of
smothering the bug in the program. The bug is that by including `jack/weak_jack.h`
you commit yourself to runtime discovery of the whole API, but don't fulfil that
committment and instead take the availability of the API for granted. Hence the
segfault with *as-needed* linkage. Linking with `-no-as-needed` just cancels the
the effect of including `jack/weak_jack.h`. Including it says your program doesn't
*need* any of the API definitions: `-no-as-needed` says, whatever they are, you're getting 
them all anyway.

In the light of the fact that all JACK APIs post version 0.116.2 are weakly
defined without resort to `jack/weak_jack.h`, I think that you simply don't
have any use for this header unless you are indeed planning a program that
will do something worthwhile on a host from which `libjack` is missing. If you
*are* planning that, then you have no alternative to runtime discovery of all
the JACK APIs you use, regardless of linkage conventions, because you can't link
`libjack` anyway.

If not, then just link `libjack` and, if you merely call `jack_client_open`,
your program, on any host, will dynamically link all the API definitions, whatever
they are on that host, because your reference to `jack_client_open` (in the
absence of `<jack/weak_jack.h>`) will make `libjack` *needed*, whether that
matters to the linker that did the linking or not. If you want to be compatible
accross API versions, then you need to implement runtime detection
[as documented](http://jackaudio.org/api/group__WeakLinkage.html)
of any API that is [documented](http://jackaudio.org/api/jack_8h.html) with the attribute `JACK_WEAK_EXPORT`
 - as opposed to `JACK_OPTIONAL_WEAK_EXPORT, or JACK_OPTIONAL_WEAK_DEPRECATED_EXPORT`: the latter denote fundamental APIs that
 can only be forcibly weakened via `<jack/weak_jack.h>`.

Comment: thanks for the long answer. please note that the segfault in my example is not the problem i'm having (i merely left it there to simplify the code - which probably has not worked out as expected; in any case the real code does proper checks to avoid a segfault). i still doubt the conclusion that defining a symbol as *weak* is practically telling the linker to just set it to `NULL` (for me, "the linker is not obliged to find a definition for it" is really a promise of best-effort, rather than "go with the simplest solution").

Comment: btw, I'm including `weak_jack.h` because the program is weakly-linked against the jack-framework on OSX builds, which works as expected. my real issue seems to be that I do not want to clutter my code with conditional ifdefs (since i actually would like to have weak-linking (in an OSX sense) on *all* platforms, and not do second guesses about which linker supports which kind of weak-linking...) - updating the question

Comment: and while I even understand "the linker, if directed to link only shared libraries that are needed, should then link libraries [...] for which you [...] have told it that definitions are not needed" my question is really asking for "how to tell the linker to only link libraries providing symbols which are referenced in the code"